# I have an unlimited German residence Visa, but I haven't been there for 6 years. Will I be able to go back with the same visa?

Tags: germany, residency

Since 1999 I lived in Germany with an unlimited Residence Visa. In 2010 I left the country and I am now living in India. Can I go back to Germany with the same Residence Visa that I already have? If I fly to Germany, will there be any problem at the destination airport?

Please give me proper guidance on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

Given that Germany does **not** record entries and exits, and also (from what I've seen) doesn't stamp passports of residence permit holders, they're unlikely to know how long you've been out of the country for, unless you went to the authorities and de-registered your residence (which you probably didn't seeing as you still have your residence permit)

If you're moving back to Germany, that shouldn't be an issue, but if you're just visiting and have no plans on moving back there, I'd say it's better to visit the German embassy, turn in your residence permit, and apply for a Schengen visa.

Comment: Actually an _unbefristete Aufenthaltsgenehmigung_ goes away if you're gone for more than half a year. But I have no idea how they check that.

Comment: @simbabque Hence the "shouldn't be an issue" - it's difficult to enforce

Comment: If the OP were continuously resident in Germany, would they have had to file tax returns? Will the returns for the missing years be an issue?